# Computing determinant of this matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a very specific kind of matrix and I have to find the formula to find the determinant of these matrix.

a(i,j)=a if(i==j) and a(i,j)=0 if(floor(i/2)=floor(j/2) and i!=j) and n is odd

$$ A=(a_{i,j})_{n \times n}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a&0&b&b \cdots &b&b\\
0& a&b&b \cdots& b&b\\
b& b& a&0 \cdots& b&b\\
b& b& 0&a \cdots& b&b\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots&\cdots\\
b&b&b & \cdots&b&a
\end{array}
\right)? $$

Comment: Try writing down its eigenvectors.

Comment: What's the rule for the placement of the $0$'s ?

Comment: a(i,j)=a if(i==j) and a(i,j)=0 if(i/2=j/2 and i!=j)

Comment: Please notice n is odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383244) posted and answered yesterday, with $p\leftarrow2$, $np\leftarrow n-1$, $c\leftarrow a/b$, with the entire matrix divided by $b$.

Since according to a comment under the question $n$ is odd, we need to deal with the last component separately. All eigenvectors in the linked question except for the one filled with $1$s sum to $0$. Thus we can append a $0$ to them to obtain eigenvectors of the present matrix. That leaves a two-dimensional subspace to be dealt with, spanned by the vector $x$ that has a $1$ in the last component and the vector $y$ that has $1$s everywhere else. Applying $A$ to these vectors yields $Ax=ax+by$ and $Ay=(n-1)bx+((n-3)b+a)y$. Thus the product of the remaining two eigenvalues is

$$
\left|\matrix{a&b\\(n-1)b&(n-3)b+a}\right|=((n-3)b+a)a-(n-1)b^2\;.
$$

Multiplying this by the $n-2$ eigenvalues from the linked question, with the above substitutions and the factor $b^{n-2}$ that was divided out, yields the determinant of the present matrix:

\begin{align}
\det A
&=
\left(((n-3)b+a)a-(n-1)b^2\right)b^{n-2}\left(\frac ab\right)^{(n-1)/2}\left(\frac ab-2\right)^{(n-3)/2}
\\
&=
\left(((n-3)b+a)a-(n-1)b^2\right)a^{(n-1)/2}\left(a-2b\right)^{(n-3)/2}\;.
\end{align}

Comment: It sounds pretty close but $n$ is odd...

Comment: @achille: Aha -- thanks for pointing that out -- yet another reminder why it's a bad idea to bury clarifications of the question deep in the comments...

Comment: Can this matrix have a particular formula?

Comment: @Alen: How do you mean, can it?

Comment: Means, can I derive a formula for calculating the det A?

Comment: @Alen: There you are.

Comment: @joriki : Sorry to ask for you favour again and again but can you please help me to understand it cause I want myself to be able to find the determinant when a(i,j)=0 if(floor(i/3)=floor(j/3) and i!=j) and time n=3*k-1. Pleaseee...

Comment: @Alen: I don't know what kind of a response you expect to "please help me understand it". If you're having trouble understanding parts of the answer, please point out which parts you don't understand and what's causing the problems.

Comment: @joriki: If I exactly have  [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383244/determinant-of-matrix) this question just with (pn-1)*(pn-1) dimension of matrix, can I get a generalized solution?

Comment: @Alen: Yes, you can proceed much like I proceeded in this answer here. You'll have $p-2$ vectors that sum to zero in the last, incomplete block (these didn't exist here in the case $p=2$), and these are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $a$; and you'll have one vector that's filled with $1$s in the last block, and that's the one you have to treat specially like I did in this answer. The fact that it had only a single entry in the present case isn't important; you can do practically the same thing I did here also if $p-1\gt1$.

Comment: @joriki: Treating the last component separately, I am not being able to understand this part. :(

Comment: @Alen: These comments are getting a bit out of hand. I don't mean anything other than what I did in this answer. If you don't see how to apply that for $p\gt2$, you should ask a separate question about that; that's not something that should be explained in comments.

Comment: @joriki: as you suggested I have asked another question. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384712/generalizing-formula-for-calculating-determinant-of-specific-matrix), please help

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ is odd, let $n = 2m+1$ and $u_n$ be the $n \times 1$ column vector with all entries one.

The matrix $A$ can be rewritten to have the form $X + b u_n u_n^{T}$ where $X$ is a block
diagonal matrix consists of $m$ $2\times 2$ block $\tilde{X}$ and one $1 \times 1$ block:

$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{X} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & \tilde{X} & 0 &\dots  & 0\\
0 & 0 & \tilde{X} &\dots  & 0\\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a - b
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }\quad \tilde{X} = \begin{pmatrix}a - b & -b\\-b & a-b\end{pmatrix}
$$

When one perturb an invertible matrix $X$ by a rank one matrix like $b u_n u_n^T$, it is known that the determinant of the updated matrix $X + b u_n u_n^{T}$ is given by:

$$\det( X + b u_n u_n^{T} ) = \det(X)( 1 + b u_n^{T} X^{-1} u_n )\tag{*}$$

Substitute our special form of $X$ into $(*)$ and notice:

$$\begin{align}
\det(X) &= \det(\tilde{X})^m (a - b) = ((a-b)^2 - b^2)^m (a - b)\\
u_n^{T} X^{-1} u_n &= m\;u_2^T \tilde{X}^{-1} u_2 + \frac{1}{a-b}
= \frac{2m}{a-2b} + \frac{1}{a-b}
\end{align}$$

We get:
$$\begin{align}
\det A &= ((a-b)^2 - b^2)^m (a - b)\left\{1 + b \left(\frac{2m}{a-2b} + \frac{1}{a-b} \right)\right\}\\
&= a^m (a-2b)^{m-1}\left(a^2 + 2 (m-1)ab - 2mb^2\right)
\end{align}$$

**Update**

For the general case when the matrix elements is given by:

$$a_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 
a, & \text{ for } i = j\\
0, & \text{ for } \lfloor\frac{i}{q}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{j}{q}\rfloor \wedge i \neq j\\
b, & \text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}$$

where $0 \le i, j < n$ and $q$ is an integer $> 1$. Let $n = mq + r$ where $0 \le r < q$. Once again, we rewrite $A$ into the form $X + b u_n u_n^T$ where X is now a block diagonal matrix consists of $m$ $q \times q$ block $\tilde{X}_q$ and one $r \times r$ block $\tilde{X}_r$.

It is not hard to verify the entries on $\tilde{X}_s$ is given by:

$$(\tilde{X}_s)_{i,j} = \begin{cases} a-b, &\text{ for } i = j\\-b, &\text{ otherwise. }\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}\det(\tilde{X}_s) &= a^{s-1}(a - sb)\\
u_s^{T} \tilde{X}_s^{-1} u_s   &= \frac{s}{a-sb}\end{cases}
$$
Repeating the same procedure as above, we obtain the formula for $\det(A)$ in the general case:

$$\det A = (a^{q-1}(a - qb))^m (a^{r-1}(a-rb)) \left\{1 + b \left(\frac{mq}{a-qb} + \frac{r}{a-rb}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: hue:r can be -1 here?

Comment: @Alen that is a typo, should be $0 \le r < q$. In principle, one should treat $r = 0$ as a special case. However, it turns out the final expression also work for the $r = 0$ case.

Comment: I was actually thinking of (pn-1)*(pn-1) dimension matrix

Comment: @Alen, your $pn-1$ case is equivalent to setting the parameters $(m,q,r)$ to $(n-1,p,p-1)$ in my answer.